DMCA notice indicates packets with wrong IPv4 destination are being received by my router
I received a DMCA notice stating that BitTorrent packets with an IPv4 destination address of 97.118.208.52 were being received by my home WIFI router even though its IPv4 address at the time (according to the ISP, CenturyLink) hadn't changed from 174.29.123.180. The session was initiated on the LAN side of the router by an app.
Here's the relevant information from the DMCA notice that my ISP forwarded to me:
Title:        Jurassic World
Timestamp:    2024-05-03T07:54:10Z
IP Address:   97.118.208.52
Port:         52382
Type:         BitTorrent
Torrent Hash: 80f13a4d3faed8a13a74f7f3b71e5e43ca5073cf
Filename:     Jurassic.World.2015.1080p.Rifftrax.6ch.2ch
Filesize:     2617 MB

The boilerplate in the notice refers to the above IP address this way:

We have become aware that an individual has utilized the IP address
97.118.208.52 at the recorded date and time below to download, host,
and/or facilitate the downloading and/or streaming of video content
that is exclusively owned by NBCUniversal.

How is this possible? How can an app on the LAN side cause reception of packets with the wrong destination address?
(Aside: The DMCA issue has been handled.)

It could be a few things. Wrong date/time on their end, they tracked it differently with multiple ip addresses and just screwed up telling you which ip address it was, or it is an imposter trying you to click a link to install malware/etc.

Some DOCSIS ISPs have a thing where your home router can publish an extra "guest" SSID like "CableWiFi" or "[ISPName]wifi" that any customer of that ISP can join if they are in range of any other participating customer's premises. The traffic doesn't count against your Mbps speed limit or monthly data caps and the traffic is completely separate from your home network. I wouldn't be surprised if such a network used a completely different subnet.

Are you sure the statement was that your router was receiving packets? Not sending them? The exact wording could be important here.

I've added details from the DMCA notice.

I'm not positive that the IP address in the DMCA notice was the destination address of incoming packets. I'm assuming it was because all the other addresses (incoming source, outgoing source and destination) would be useless for identifying my router/modem.

Those are all questions you need to ask the ISP. The content enforcement folks can't identify YOU specifically, they can just identify the ISP, and then the ISP forwards the DMCA notices to you. only the ISP can tell you why they think this is your problem.

@FrankThomas, I tried. CenturyLink's support was inadequate. I accept CenturyLink's assertion. I just don't understand the invalid IP address, which is why I asked if the BitTorrent client could change the external address of my router/modem.

well, if the party who did the deed used a proxy or VPN that would cause the IP address to appear different upstream at the swarm, but it would have to be a flawed implementation, since clearly the protections were pierced. but no, a bittorrent client cannot change your public IP at the ISP, especially to an address not owned by the ISP.

@FrankThomas, it would seem, then, that the bogus IP address is an incoming source address or an outgoing destination address. Either way, it's useless to me. Rats.

You haven't stated how you got the DMCA notice, nor how they told you that "my home WiFi router" was involved.
For example, if someone else is using your account and is doing something wrong, it's "your account" that's involved, not your "home WiFi router". In that case, the infringing IP address would tell you where "your account" was being abused.
In other cases, Network Address Translation may be translating your IP address even though your "WiFi router" thinks it has a fixed IP address.
